# Energy Continuity Equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology

I have the following equation (Energy Continuity Equation) derived from Einstein/Friedmann equations:

$$ \dot \rho + 3\left(\rho + P\right)\frac{\dot a}{a} = 0 $$

Now, I then have to show that $\rho \propto a^{-3}$ for $P=0$. I've been looking around on the web, and everytime I just see a $\Rightarrow$ between the above equation and $\rho \propto a^{-3}$ as it being very trivial. Don't know if it's because it's late or what, but I can't see why it is.

So I was hoping someone might knew.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dot{\rho}+3(\rho+P)\frac{\dot{a}}{a}=0$$
with $P=0$, leads to
$$\dot{\rho}+3\rho\frac{\dot{a}}{a}=0$$
$$\dot{\rho}=-3\rho\frac{\dot{a}}{a}$$
$$\frac{\dot{\rho}}{\rho}=-3\frac{\dot{a}}{a}$$
$$\frac{\frac{d\rho}{dt}}{\rho}=-3\frac{\frac{da}{dt}}{a}$$
$$\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{d\rho}{dt}=-3\frac{1}{a}\frac{da}{dt}$$
$$\int\frac{1}{\rho}d\rho=-3\int\frac{1}{a}da$$
From here, it's easy to show that
$$\rho \propto a^{-3}$$

Comment: No problem. I can assure you I've felt stupider.

Answer (score 0):

For $P=0$ the equation becomes $$\dot\rho+3 \rho\frac{d}{dt}{\log a}=0.$$ So $$\frac{d}{dt}(\log\rho+3\log a)=0$$ And Thus
$$
\rho\propto a^{-3}.
$$